# is it possible to use the path when using git to add the dependencies in rust cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to add the cargo dependencies `rocket-okapi` as git url, now I added the dependencies like in `Cargo.toml` this:

```
rocket-okapi = { git = "https://github.com/GREsau/okapi/tree/master/rocket-okapi"}
```

but when I build the project using `cargo build` command ,shows error like this:

```
 $ cargo build
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/GREsau/okapi/tree/master/rocket-okapi`
warning: spurious network error (2 tries remaining): unexpected http status code: 404; class=Http (34)
warning: spurious network error (1 tries remaining): unexpected http status code: 404; class=Http (34)
error: failed to get `rocket-okapi` as a dependency of package `fortune v0.1.0 (/workspaces/fortune)`

Caused by:
  failed to load source for dependency `rocket-okapi`

Caused by:
  Unable to update https://github.com/GREsau/okapi/tree/master/rocket-okapi

Caused by:
  failed to fetch into: /home/codespace/.cargo/git/db/rocket-okapi-b6c0b0836896ac76

Caused by:
  network failure seems to have happened
  if a proxy or similar is necessary `net.git-fetch-with-cli` may help here
  https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#netgit-fetch-with-cli

Caused by:
  unexpected http status code: 404; class=Http (34)
```

how to add the sub folder as dependencies in rust cargo? is it possible?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to use `https://github.com/GREsau/okapi.git` instead of some random point in the repository's tree?

Comment: I read the official document from https://docs.rs/rocket_okapi/latest/rocket_okapi/ and it both using okapi and rocket-okapi.@gspr

Comment: this url works fine in my browser. @gspr

Comment: Do `rocket_okapi = { git = "https://github.com/GREsau/okapi" }`. See [this reply to an issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1462#issuecomment-87002475).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things here that need a bit of clarification.

When you add a Git dependency to `Cargo.toml`, it expects a repository. The URL you put in there is a directory *in* the repository, so `cargo` freaks out.

Secondly, when a Git dependency is specified, `cargo` first looks in the repository root for a `Cargo.toml` file. If it cannot find any, it will search for *any* `Cargo.toml` files where the package name is the same as the dependency.

The dependency you specified, `rocket-okapi`, doesn't exist in the repository, so `cargo` gives up. Changing the name of the dependency to 'rocket_okapi' fixes this.

TL;DR: Use this

```ini
rocket_okapi = { git = "https://github.com/GREsau/okapi" }
```